# Filling up of orbitals

Tags: quantum-chemistry, electrons, electronic-configuration

As we know that the orbitals in a sub shell are degenerate, so is it necessary to fill up the electrons starting from x then to y and then z (if in p-subshell) or they can be filled like shown in the photo. [image]

Comment: Short answer: it makes no difference. Long answer involves QM.

Comment: The very word "degenerate" means they are exactly identical, so there is no difference. If we commonly fill them up left to right, it's just a conventional thing, much like writing left to right.

Comment: If you think back to math class one variable is usually x, two use x-y plane and three dimension use x,y and z. Chemists tend to do it that same way.

Answer (score 2):

You are drawing very nice $\mathrm{p}_x$, $\mathrm{p}_y$ and $\mathrm{p}_z$ orbitals onto that piece of paper. But if you take an isolated atom, which direction is $x$? Which is $y$? The coordinate system you’re seeing the atom in is just something we planted over its top because humans like things nice and organised. It is entirely arbitrary.

By the way, the direct calculations do not give $\mathrm{p}_x$ and $\mathrm{p}_y$ orbitals (strictly speaking not even $\mathrm{p}_z$. They give you $\mathrm{p}_0$, $\mathrm{p}_1$ and $\mathrm{p}_{-1}$ (the indices referring to the value of $m_l$, the ‘magnetical quantum number’). In spherical coordinates, [which are used because it makes the calculations easier](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/39680/7475), only the $z$ axis is semi-defined by values $\theta = 0$. Because $\psi(\mathrm{p}_0) = f(r, \theta)$ (the wavefunction of one of the p-orbitals is independent of $\phi$), we say that this represents the $\mathrm{p}_z$ orbital. $\mathrm{p}_1$ and $\mathrm{p}_{-1}$ (the direct solutions of the Hamiltonian) cannot even be mapped to directions as they involve complex numbers; only *via* linear combinations can we transform them into two real orbitals pointing in an arbitrary $x$ and an arbitrary $z$ direction.

Things change if you introduce an external magnetic field. The atom’s $z$ axis will now align with the magnetic field in some way, giving your system *one* preferred direction. One, not three. $x$ and $y$ are still essentially undefined. However, in a magnetic field it *would* make a difference which orbitals the electrons populate.

You might also be interested in checking out the [Jahn-Teller effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jahn%E2%80%93Teller_effect) which occurs in transition metal chemistry to avoid filling some of all degenerate orbitals. In a nutshell it is energetically better for certain complexes to distort themself from a perfect octahedron to create distinct energy levels that can be fully populated, half populated or unpopulated.

Answer (score 1):

The pure answer is, you can unitarily transform them into each other.

In the classical mechanic picture assume a coordinate system you put somewhere onto a map in a way that one car is driving along the y-axis and another one along the x-axis in the same speed and momentum hence same kinetic energy. Nothing stops you from arbitrarily rotating or mirroring this coordinate system so that for example one car is driving along the z-axis and another one along the x-axis.

At least to be honest there is still the possibility that you have negative velocities if you would mirror, but the kinetic energy is still unaffected. And we are interested into the energies.

When starting with px and pz orbitals you could arbitrarily switch your coordinate system and start with py and px orbitals.

Comment: Since velocity is essentially a vector, ‘negative’ only has the meaning of velocity pointing in the opposite direction.